# x64dbg, breakpoint on write in memory with specific value

Tags: x64dbg, breakpoint

In x64dbg, we can set hardware breakpoint on write in memory dump but can we add more codition? 
Ex. Set breakpoin on write of value of 2F.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that. Once you set the hardware breakpoint you can go to `Breakpoints` tab, right click the breakpoint on which you want to set condition, and select `Edit`. Now you can set the break condition.

Let's say your value is written to the memory in such way `mov dword ptr ds:[edx],eax`, so you can set the `Break condition` to `EAX==2F`, and then the program will be interrupted only when the value to write is equal to 2F.