# How to whitelist an address for breakpoint?

Tags: x64dbg

If I have breakpoint on some win function, how to whitelist some address on which I don't want stopping?

Seems that it is needed to use conditions. How?

I use x64dbg, but if you only know a way in another debugger - it is also interesting.

Comment: what do you mean by "address on which I don't want stopping"? could you add an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that. If you don't know how to set conditional breakpoints take a look [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25215/x64dbg-breakpoint-on-write-in-memory-with-specific-value)

The condition you need to set depends if you are debugging 32 (EIP register) or 64 (RIP register) bit program.
So for example let's say you don't want to stop at address 0xDEADBEEF for 32 bit program, you can set the break condition to `EIP != DEADBEEF`. You can add multiple addresses like this: `EIP != addy1 && EIP != addy2` and so on.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Is there a good guide for conditions syntax to learn?

Comment: You can take a look there: https://help.x64dbg.com/en/latest/introduction/ConditionalBreakpoint.html https://help.x64dbg.com/en/latest/introduction/Expressions.html https://help.x64dbg.com/en/latest/introduction/Expression-functions.html